# How to scale an image with css to fill a div keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to fill a div with an `img`, keeping aspect ratio and stretching either width or height as much as required to fit in.

```
<div style="width: 80px; height: 80px">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

How could I achieve it? If the image is not quadratic, it must be "zoomed in" and either be scropped top-bottom or left-right, depending which side is the bigger one. Moreover the image should afterwards be centered, so that the corners get cut equally.

I tried (but no effect):

```
.thumb {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

If I add additional `width: 100%; height:100%;`, the images fit perfectly, but are resized not keeping `aspect ratio`.

Comment: Do you want to fill the whole div with your image and resize with it but also keep the aspect ratio?

Comment: I believe you are searching for something like `object-fit`

An example of how it works: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

IE is missing support although

Comment: If you do not need this image in source, than you better use background-image.

Answer (score 80):

the following did the trick:

```
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Be aware though that this [won't work in Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit).

Comment: Also, saying "all the presented solutions did not work", comes a bit strange to me, as the solutions from [MoLow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31943861/2167159), [Greg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31943806/2167159) and [my own solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31943841/2167159) seem to be working.

Comment: also `object-fit: scale-down;`, then `overflow: hidden;` is redundant

Comment: thank you for this, this did it for me. including the height was the bit I had missing. Once width, height and object-fit:cover were combined then everything worked perfectly (provided the outer div had a set width and height to determine its size and position on the page)

Answer (score 14):

Using `max-width`, the image will be **contained inside the div**, there will be no overflow.

If you use `min-width` instead, the shorter side will be exactly 100% of the div while the other side can be longer.
To center the image, we can use [translate and relative positioning](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

The following code works.

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
} 
.thumb {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

To keep an image's aspect ratio, just specify one dimension:

```
div {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will produce the following effect:

[image: kitten!]

However, as you can see, the kitten is not central, but you can use Flex box to sort this out.

```
div {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

img {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: both approaches do not work: In neither case the width of the parent is respected

Answer (score 5):

use background-size:cover

```css
div{
  background-image:url(http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  }
```

```html
<div style="width:80px;height:80px;"></div>
```

Comment: It works visually but know that SEO doesn't pick up on that image

Answer (score 4):

```
.thumb {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Or ( to allow scale up and down, which will look pixelated if you scale up, where the above will only scale to the max size of the image )

```
.thumb {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Is what you are looking for.

More info on responsive images:

1. http://demosthenes.info/blog/586/CSS-Fluid-Image-Techniques-for-Responsive-Site-Design
2. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

Comment: No, because images where width > height won't fill the whole space. Moreover, images are not centered after crop.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if anyone still looking at this post. I came across this while I was looking for a way to fit a image into a < div > without getting the unwanted white space around the image, because I was using hover & stick-out effect.
I was inspired by Matt's solution. 
Instead of

```
.thumb {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;}
```

I added

```
.thumb {
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
height:auto;}
```

Now my images fit in to the < div > perfectly without having those white space stick out with the image.